# How to configure neo4j.log in Neo4j 3.0.x?

Tags: neo4j

I'm running Community Edition Neo4j 3.0.3. Our neo4j.log gets to 17GB from stack traces. In Neo4j Operations Manual, Appendix A, Reference, 
https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/
we can configure HTTP log, GC log(garbage collection), debug log, query log. But I didn't find how to configure neo4j.conf, such as its rotation.size.

How can I set the size limit of neo4j.log?

Answer (score 1):

The neo4j.log file is a redirection to STDOUT. You can use logrotate to implement your own rotation strategy.

Note: When you implement a default logrotate strategy, Neo4j will not be able to write to that file anymore after a rotation.

Solution: You can use "copytruncate" in your logrotate configuration file.

A simple logrotate example I use in prod is

```
/usr/local/neo4j/logs/neo4j.log {
    su neo4j neo4j
    copytruncate
    rotate 4
    daily
    compress
    missingok
    notifempty
}
```

Note 2 : There is a very small time slice between copying the file and truncating it, so some logging data might be lost. When this option is used, the create option will have no effect, as the old log file stays in place.

Reference : http://www.delafond.org/traducmanfr/man/man8/logrotate.8.html